# What is the equivalent of NSUserDefaults/SharedPreferences for a web application?

Tags: android, flutter, web-applications, sharedpreferences, nsuserdefaults

From what I understand iOS and Android can use a thing called "NS User Defaults / Shared Preferences" to work with small bits of non-complex data.

I was wondering in a web application, what would the equivalent of this be? Or does it even exist? If not, what would a recommended / best-practice solution be?

Thank you.

Comment: I would assume local storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @NicoSpencer However, I don't think local storage will work for me since the data will not persist if the user clears cookies or is browsing in private/incognito mode in the browser. And there is no code available just a discussion on a possible approach on a higher level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the equivalent of "NSUserDefaults / SharedPreferences" that flutter provides out of the box for web is "local storage", which will not permanently persist data if the user clears browser cookies or is browsing in private/incognito mode.

This is not an ideal solution since I need data to persist permanently on the web-side of things.

The browser does not let you store data permanently, users can always clear their data whenever they choose to.

I will have to create a custom database table and sync the data from the local "NSUserDefaults/SharedPreferences" to the custom table on a server that the web app can utilize.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `SharedPreferences` in Android, iOS & Web try [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package

Comment: Hmm, how does this package handle web "shared preferences" behind the scenes? Does it use local storage / cookies? If so it will not work for my needs. May have to play with the package, otherwise I was just going to create a MySQL table and sync the "shared preferences" for the web application.

Comment: yes it looks like "shared preferences" for web on flutter uses local storage, which will not persist data for the long term.

https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/monepx/question_how_does_shared_preferences_behave_for/

I will most likely just have to create a database table on the web server.

Comment: Even if you manage to save data to the browser permanently, there is no guarantee the user will use the same browser every time. So going with DB server will be the best idea for web apps.